# Unable to execute the Producer while adding delay header

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I want to delay the message by a particular time being scheduled to be delivered by the broker.

**Producer.java**

```
    @Component
public class kafkaProducerRoute extends RouteBuilder{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        int delayMs=10000;

       from("timer:time")
                // loop over the route 10 times
                 .setHeader("delay", constant(delayMs))
                 .setBody().constant("Hello, World!")
                .to("kafka:hell1?brokers=localhost:9092")  // send the message to a Kafka topic using the Kafka producer endpoint
                .log("Message is produced");



    }
}
```

After Running the Routes I am getting an error ":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Magic v1 does not support record headers"
[image]

How to Solve this, Or is there any alternative way to Produce delay message.

Comment: You are confusing endpoint **parameters** and **headers**. Simply put your `delay` as query param: `from("timer:time?delay="+delayMs)`

Answer (score 1):

Apache Kafka does not have a concept of delaying sending messages (Some JMS brokers have that).

So do you want Camel to "delay 10 seconds", the you can use the `delay` in the route, such as `.delay(10000)` to wait 10 seconds. However this will block the thread.